# Stop form from scrolling when moving controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with autoscroll on, and I have a user-editable area in the form. Users can resize or move controls.

When moving the controls, if they are moved beyond the form's client area, the scrollbars will show. This is my intention.

Now, the form will automatically scroll down, so while the user doesn't release the mouse, the control will keep being moved down. This is obviously not intended.

I have tried disabling autoscrool when the moving (or resizing) begins, but no good... If the control is beyond the form's client are, once the moving begins it gets moved up (or left).

What is the way to lock the scroolbar when I am moving child controls?

---EDIT: sample code---

Just an example on the moving of the controls.

```
//Start moving if the button is clicked on
public void Button1_OnMouseDown()
{
   _moving=true;

}


//If the button was clicked on, move it to mouse position
public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if(_moving)
         Button1.Location=new Poiny(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

When I move out of the form's boundary, scroolbars appear and start rolling down/right to fit the controls... which in turn moves the controls since there is a mouse move event, and so on...

Comment: My suggestion would be to prevent moving beyond the form's client area. You know the control's width, the mouse's position etc, it should be easy enough to do. And/or prevent selecting controls that are (partially) beyond the client area (or, once selected, set the scrollposition high enough so it is "in view").

Comment: Ah, the thing is I need the extra space... The data i am displaying/editing could and probably would not fit on the form.

Comment: You might think of the area where you work on class diagram on visual studio... diagrams could go beyond what's visible, as with my data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prevent the `Form` or `Panel` from scrolling by overriding the `ScrollToControl` method, e.g:

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
    Point pt = this.AutoScrollPosition;
    return pt;
}
```