# Scrollbars automatic centering

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, centering

I have a Form with height size bigger then screen, so the user can use the scrollbar to see the content. My problem is, I have alot of buttons and checkboxes, all the way up and down the form, and every time the user try to click some, the form automatic try to center the clicked button in the middle of screen.

I want the scrollbar to stay where the user put it. And not trying to automatic center at every btn or iten clicked.

Can someone help with this? Its winforms, visual studio 15.

Comment: Have you looked at the AutoScroll property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a62htd5x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: AutoScroll is set to true on properties. This is the way im geting the scrollbar to show up. If i set to false, the scrollbar disapear and the content dont show.

Comment: Is there a way to make scrollbar visible without using AutoScroll option??

Comment: Have a look at AutoScrollMargin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollmargin(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not working for me, but tnk you for trying to help my friend. Still cant get it done yet.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this - I have a Windows form with a height of 600 and autoscroll = true, and a child panel with a height of 2000 (so that it overflows the form).  The panel contains buttons and checkboxes that start off off-screen, and when I click them, it doesn't automatically scroll anywhere.  Do you have some sort of layout control other than Panel that holds all of your buttons and checkboxes that might be introducing this behavior?

Comment: Nop, i just have a panel inside my form, that hold all the buttons, and this panel is set autoscroll = true. If you put the buttons far from each other verticaly, the scrollbar will adjust to put the button on middle of screen, as soon as you click. This behavior is normal according to MSDN. Our friend here tell to override my panel ScrolltoControl method, but i dont know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem but have you tried overriding the `ScrollToControl`?

[Stop form from scrolling when moving controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512355/stop-form-from-scrolling-when-moving-controls)