# Why does my FlowLayoutPanel automatically scroll back to the top when the form loses and regains focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I am creating an image browser that uses a `FlowLayoutPanel` to display thumbnails of images. See animated GIF that shows how I scroll down the panel, switch to another window, and then back to the form which causes the `FlowLayoutPanel` to scroll back to the top. I can't imagine any reason why it would do this.

Also, I seem to be able set the scroll location by clicking on the panel. When the form loses and regains focus, it scrolls back to the last Y position that I clicked.

Why is it exhibiting this behavior and how can I prevent it from occurring?

[image]

Comment: Do any of those controls (thumbnails) have some kind of focus?...causing it to jump back to whatever control is focused?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Looks like they do. All of those icons are custom controls that contain a PictureBox and a label. I handled the `GotFocus` event on the control itself and it fired when I clicked on it. Still, I wonder why it would want to scroll back to the control that has the focus only when the form loses/regains focus

Comment: @Idle_Mind I'll also add that it doesn't exhibit this behavior unless I first interact with something in the flow panel.

Comment: Maybe try extending `FlowLayoutPanel` and override the `ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)` method, e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512355/stop-form-from-scrolling-when-moving-controls/32513432#32513432

Comment: @Loathing I'll consider that as a last resort. Not really wanting to refactor code in my form and c# by creating a control that inherits from FlowLayoutPanel just to override a single property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect described is quite common: when a FlowLayoutPanel contains Controls that can be activated and one of these child Controls is selected at some point (in this case a UserControl, which has the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` extended style, so [SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle) won't do much) and the FlowLayoutPanel is then scrolled to hide this Control, when the Form is deactivated and then activated again, the [ActiveControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol) is scrolled into view.

This causes the FlowLayoutPanel to scroll to a position where the child ActiveControl is visible.

▶ This doesn't happen when the child Controls are not selectable, as the PictureBox Control, for example. If this Control were used to present the thumbnails (as shown in the question), the FlowLayoutPanel would not scroll.

I think the simplest way to prevent the FlowLayoutPanel from scrolling to the ActiveControl is to set the FlowLayoutPanel itself as the ActiveControl when the Form is deactivated, handling the [Deactivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate) event.

```
private void form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = this.flowLayoutPanel1;
}
```

This has no meaningful side affects, except the Control that previously was the ActiveControl will raise the `Leave` event.
It may be also used to suspend some other *activity*, since the User is now focusing on another Window.

▶ To set the ActiveControl to the default one instead (the Control that is activated when the Form is first shown), set **`this.ActiveControl = null;`**. It will be reset when the Form is activated again.

I've seen sometimes the `Activated` and `Deactivate` events used to disable and enable back a ContainerControl: this also prevents the scrolling, of course, but may cause  unwanted cascading effects when child Controls are disabled.
But it may also be something expected and possibly desired. It depends on what happens behind the scene (implementation details).

The solution proposed by [@Loathing in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110560/why-does-my-flowlayoutpanel-automatically-scroll-back-to-the-top-when-the-form-l/64111754#comment113370321_64110560) can also work, deriving a Custom Control from FlowLayoutPanel. It depends on the use case.
[Stop form from scrolling when moving controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513432/7444103)

Comment: Yep, so far your solution is working well. No more annoying auto-scrolling. In the future, if I have other controls that I would like to remain focused, I will check if any of those controls have the focus, store a reference to the control during the Deactivated event, and then set it back to the active control on Activate. Will cross that bridge when I get to it, but I am sure it will work.