# YouTube Player - when exiting fullscreen mode the WebView2 Browser moves

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube, media-player, webview2

From my previous question:
[How do I get YouTube native player to allow full screen in WebView2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77180357/7444103)
I'm using the code provided there.

I have an issues with my YouTube player. Once I exit Fullscreen mode the player moves in relation to my Panel Control Scroll bar position.
I have provided images and my code.

Another issue I am having, is the YouTube player does go to Fullscreen, however, it will maximize the size of the panel control instead of a specific size.

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class HowToViewSites : CMBaseDialog
    {
        private Size originalSize = new Size(700, 375);
        private Point originalLocation = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 269);
        private Size maxFullscreenSize = new Size(1920, 1080);
        private bool isFullScreen = false;
        private FormWindowState originalWindowState;
        private FormBorderStyle originalFormBorderStyle;
        public HowToViewSites() => InitializeComponent();

        protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            await InitializeWebView2();

            var videoSource = new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgMnE1No_6A");
            var videoId = videoSource.Query.Substring(videoSource.Query.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
            webView21.NavigateToString(GetHTMLContent(videoId, new Size(700, 375)));
        }

        private async Task InitializeWebView2()
        {           
            var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions(null, null, "", false);
            var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync("", null, options);

            webView21.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
        }

        private void WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsSuccess)
            {
                webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsWebMessageEnabled = true;
                webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsScriptEnabled = true;

                webView21.WebMessageReceived += async (o, a) => {
                    string message = a.TryGetWebMessageAsString();
                    switch (message)
                    {
                        case "Player initialized":
                            // Starts the playback after the YT Player has been initialized
                            await Task.Delay(200);
                            await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("ResumeVideo()");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Debug.WriteLine(message);
                            break;
                    }
                };

                webView21.CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElementChanged += (o, a) => {
                    RequestFullscreen(webView21.CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElement);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Core WebView component initialization failed");
                Application.ExitThread();
            }
        }

        public void RequestFullscreen(bool isFullScreen)
        {
            if (isFullScreen)
            {
                // Store original values
                originalWindowState = WindowState;
                originalFormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle;

                // Enter fullscreen mode
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                webView21.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webView21.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                // Restore original values when exiting fullscreen mode
                WindowState = originalWindowState;
                FormBorderStyle = originalFormBorderStyle;
                webView21.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            }

            this.isFullScreen = isFullScreen;
        }
        private string GetHTMLContent(string videoId, Size videoSize)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(@"
        <html>
        <head>
            <!-- Include the YouTube iframe API script using HTTPS -->
            <script src='https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>
            <script>
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('playerframe', {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                },
                videoId: '[VIDEO-ID]',
                height: '[VIDEO-HEIGHT]',
                width: '[VIDEO-WIDTH]',
                playerVars : {
                    'enablejsapi' : 1
                }});
            }

            function StopVideo() { player.stopVideo(); }
            function PauseVideo() { player.pauseVideo(); }
            function ResumeVideo() { player.playVideo(); }

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                // Player is ready
                window.chrome.webview.postMessage('Player initialized');
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Element replaced with an IFrame when the YouType Player is initialized -->
            <div id='playerframe'></div>
        </body>
        </html>
    ");

            sb = sb.Replace("[VIDEO-ID]", videoId)
                   .Replace("[VIDEO-HEIGHT]", videoSize.Height.ToString())
                   .Replace("[VIDEO-WIDTH]", videoSize.Width.ToString());

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Thank you very much for any help provide.

Comment: When you take code from anywhere, you have to reference the source. I've added it for you. -- A scrollable ContainerControl scrolls to the active control; see the notes here: [Why does my FlowLayoutPanel automatically scroll back to the top when the form loses and regains focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64111754/7444103) -- In case it cannot directly move to he top position, you can make it scroll to (0, 0)  yourself

Comment: Thank you so much! I will reference the code used next time. :)